# How can I install Chocolatey with the file chocolatey.0.10.15.nupkg?

Tags: powershell, nuget, chocolatey

I have an error in the PowerShell console with Chocolatey's link.

[chocolatey's link error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1x8Rh.png)

If have not a solution, I need to learn how to install Chocolatey with the downloaded file "chocolatey.0.10.15.nupkg".

[chocolatey's file .nupkg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fq6Bt.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing choco is a very common use case, including NuGet.

PowerShell already comes with a package manager that uses NuGet that it already installs by default. You can still install choco for other reasons, but for every day, normal PowerShell use, it's not needed.

> > Installing PowerShellGet
> > https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/gallery/installing-psget?view=powershell-7
>
> PowerShellGet is an in-box module in the following releases Windows 10
> or newer Windows Server 2016 or newer Windows Management Framework
> (WMF) 5.0 or newer PowerShell 6

Set your security level in your PowerShell session.

```
# Required for use with web SSL sites
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

If your ExecutionPolicy is set to AllSigned, then any script you run must be signed. Otherwise, set the ExecutionPolicy to RemoteSigned or ByPass in your user session.

[How to Install Chocolatey using PowerShell](https://mcsaguru.com/install-chocolatey-using-powershell)

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; Invoke-Expression (
    (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1')
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have Windows 7 and PowerShell 2.0. I do it your steps but I still have one error. Excepción al llamar a "DownloadString" con los argumentos "1": "Se ha terminado la conexión: Error inesperado de envío."
En línea: 1 Carácter: 118
+ Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; Invoke-Expression ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString <<<< ('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
    + CategoryInfo: NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Comment: If this is your personal machine, upgrade your PS version to PSv5x. PS2 is no longer supported  ([depreciated](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/windows-powershell-2-0-deprecation/)) and really should no longer be used. Also, choco has system requirements.. [Does your system meet the requirements?](https://chocolatey.org/courses/getting-started/requirements)

Comment: I installed chocolatey by downloading Windows Management Framework 5.1 that include PowerShell 5.1. Thanks you very much!!